# Button Pressed State Ignores CornerRadius Setting

Tags: xaml, uwp

I can't seem to find any help on getting the pressed state for a button to respect the corner radius being set. This is working for the normal, hover and disabled states. As you can see I've tried setting the corner radius in the visual state and the content presenter, but this didn't help in either case. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I'm using to set the corner radius:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RoundButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="CornerRadius">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF005250"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#80005250"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="CornerRadius">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF005250"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF005250"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="CornerRadius">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF424A51"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFCCD2D6"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF424A51"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="CornerRadius">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          CornerRadius="5"
                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Try to move the CornerRadius=5 in the "RootGrid" instead of the "ContenPresenter"

Comment: That worked! If you want to add as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Move the CornerRadius = 5 in the "RootGrid", instead of the "ContentPresenter"

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RoundButton" TargetType="Button">
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid"
      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
      CornerRadius="5">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="CornerRadius">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF005250"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#80005250"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="CornerRadius">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF005250"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF005250"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="CornerRadius">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF424A51"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFCCD2D6"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF424A51"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="CornerRadius">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
</Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```